# A CSS class is not showing/working in network console

Tags: html, css

I was writing some code and create a class for a table using bootstrap. I return to the code page after save it and load the localhost server but nothing got modify. I open the console and the css that I just saved doesn't appear. Hope you guys can understand whats happening. Any other css that I wrote in the main.css page worked correctly. 
If i don't call css and i just modify the line with style it work but I want it to be call by css.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-auto">
```

This is my code

[image: This is my code]

This is the console it is not getting the new class css element

[image: This is the console it is not getting the new class css element]

Comment: Is the above CSS in a new file that you've created? If so, please confirm that you've linked it to the page containing the table. Any media queries being used in the CSS we cannot see?

Comment: Either the class is being overridden or maybe you need to clean cache for the style to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to use cmd alt R to reload from inicial folder and not getting the caché load first.